# pyspark select column dynamically

Tags: pyspark

I have the following example dataframe:

```
data = [(1,2),(3,4)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = ['Vol 2020','Vol 2021'])
```

[image]

I want to write my own function (without using the unpivot function in pyspark) to create another dataframe such as this:

[image]

I have written it to basically say if the column exists, then select that column otherwise select NULL as that column:

```
years = ["2020","2021","2022"]
columns = df1.schema.simpleString()

emptyRDD = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(emptyRDD,schema)

for y in years:
  column_name = "Vol " + y
  if column_name in columns:
    df_2 = df_2.union(df1.select(lit(y).alias("Year"), col(column_name).alias("Volume")))
  else:
    df_2 = df_2.union(df1.select(lit(y).alias("Year"), lit(None).alias("Volume")))
```

I was hoping to that all in one line but got `` cannot resolve '`Vol 2022`' given input columns: [Vol 2020, Vol 2021]; `` error

```
for y in years:
  column_name = "Vol " + y
  df_2 = df_2.union(df1.select(lit(y).alias("Year"), when(lit("Vol " + y in columns) == True, col("Vol " + y)).otherwise(lit(None)).alias("Volume")))
```

If I remove the lit in `lit("Vol " + y in columns) == True` then I get the `condition should be a Column` error

Comment: you have to use the `lit` because the `when` function requires a column for the condition. you could simply use python's `if` -- `col('vol '+y).alias('volume') if 'vol '+y in columns else lit(None).alias('volume')`